# Incorrect username or password while getting Access Token in Azure

Tags: rest, azure, jwt, access-token, azure-api-apps

Here's my code for getting the access token:

```
HttpClient clie = new HttpClient();
    string tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{directoryID}/oauth2/token";
    var body = "resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&client_id=clientID&grant_type=password&username=myADusername&password=myADpassword";
   var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

 var result = await clie.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
                {
                    return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                });

                JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(result);

                var token = jobject["access_token"].Value<string>();
```

I am using my Azure AD username and password to get the token.  I have used the same credentials in my MVC app `var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username,Password);` which works fine.  But in this .NET core 2.0 app it gives me an error saying invalid grant. Invalid username or password. These are the same credentials that I've used to get the token, the grant type is set to password.  What is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: You need to URL-encode the values. You can use `FormUrlEncodedContent` instead of `StringContent` to do all of it in an easier way.

Comment: I tried that using Postman but it is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, the demo code is working for me. If possible, please have a try to create a new user in the your Azure AD and use the created user to test it again.
username format is `username@xxx.xxx`

```
HttpClient clie = new HttpClient();
string tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";
var body = "resource=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api&client_id={nativeAppClientId}&grant_type=password&username=username@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com&password=password";
var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string result =  clie.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith((response) =>
            {
                return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }).Result;
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: The username I'm using is my AD username with the format:  xxx@domain.com and not xxx@domain.onmicrosoft.com.  If I use the former format I get the same error - Invalid credentials.  But if the I use the latter one I get an error saying that this application must be added to ... directory.  I also wanted to point out that while I was working with an MVC application, I used the same username and password and it was working.